# Open a prespective on eclipse startup - programmatically

Tags: java, eclipse, plugins, eclipse-plugin

I am developing a eclipse plugin. I need to open my prespective when we open the eclipse at first time. Any ways to achieve this? i guess some listener must be available but could not trace out.

We can open a prespective after eclipse start using `PlatformUI.getWorkbench().showPrespective(<prespective id>)`

Similarly is there a way to open the prespective on eclipse startup, so that our desired prespective gets opened when starting the eclipse.

Comment: Is your plugin for your own eclipse product, an RCP application or for any typical eclipse installation a user chooses to install it in?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the `org.eclipse.ui.startup` extension point in your plugin. When the plugin is activated, check/set a preference to decide if you want to switch perspectives and then schedule a `UIJob` do do it.

1. Implement the extension point. Some class in the plugin needs `implements org.eclipse.ui.IStartup`. The activator class is fine in this case. Particularly, since you don't need anything in the `earlyStartup` method.
2. In the `start` method, make the decision to switch and schedule it:

   ```
   public void start(BundleContext context) throws Exception {
       super.start(context);
       plugin = this;

       final boolean switchPerpective = processPluginUpgrading();
       if (switchPerpective) {
           final IWorkbench workbench = PlatformUI.getWorkbench();
           new UIJob("Switching perspectives"){
               @Override
               public IStatus runInUIThread(IProgressMonitor monitor) {
                   try {
                       workbench.showPerspective(perspectiveId, workbench.getActiveWorkbenchWindow());
                   } catch (WorkbenchException e) {
                       return new Status(IStatus.ERROR,PLUGIN_ID,"Error while switching perspectives", e);
                   }
                   return Status.OK_STATUS;
               }}
           .run(new NullProgressMonitor());
       }
   }
   ```
3. Use the preference store to keep data for your decision logic. In this implementation, the perspective is switched once per workspace whenever the plugin is upgraded. The data recorded in the preference store will allow a future version to have a difference policy. It uses the `getPreferenceStore` from `AbstractUIPlugin` so it is scoped per workspace. If you want to use other scopes, see the [FAQ](http://wiki.eclipse.org/FAQ_How_do_I_use_the_preference_service?).

   ```
   private Boolean processPluginUpgrading() {
       final Version version = getDefault().getBundle().getVersion();
       final IPreferenceStore preferenceStore = getDefault().getPreferenceStore();
       final String preferenceName = "lastVersionActivated";
       final String lastVersionActivated = preferenceStore.getString(preferenceName);
       final boolean upgraded = 
               "".equals(lastVersionActivated)
               || (version.compareTo(new Version(lastVersionActivated)) > 0);
       preferenceStore.setValue(preferenceName, version.toString());
       return upgraded;
   }
   ```

Answer (score 1):

One thing I am doing to open my custom perspective in my plugin is to configure it in `config.ini` in eclipe's installation folder as below:

```
-perspective <my perspective id>
```

and it is working fine. I got this information from Lars Vogel's tutorial, which you can find [here](http://www.vogella.com/blog/2011/11/02/eclipse-setting-the-default-perspective-via-config-ini/). Hope this helps.

Other way:

`org.eclipse.ui.IPerspectiveRegistry.setDefaultPerspective(id)` this sets default perspective to the given id.  [API Docs for the same.](http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/api/org/eclipse/ui/IPerspectiveRegistry.html)

Comment: Thanks Pradeep for your solution. it works. But i need it to be done programtically. Because i m developing a plugin and all my files will be in a jar. So once the eclipse is started the jar will load and i need to set the default prespective to my own prespective at this time. Any ideas?

Comment: @Simz : How to get the perspective ID? In my case I want C/C++ perspective ID? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

**Go to**

```
D:\{MyTestSpace}\eclipse\features\myCustom.plugin.feature_3.1.0.201607220552
```

you can see `feature.xml` under plugin tag you get the id.

Use this id in `config.ini` which you can find under

`D:\{MyTestSpace}\eclipse\configuration`

**As**

```
-perspective <myCustum.plugin>
```